# Code for checking to see if a new message with a specific subject line has been already created Lotus

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not a programmer so I apologize in advance.

I have three different worksheets in a workbook. Each sheet has a specific macro so that after numbers are entered, shift supervisors can press a button with the assigned macro and metrics from that sheet will be copied and pasted to a different worksheet in a format with filter-able/pivot-able columns. It then saves and closes the data, goes back to the shift report worksheet, copies the pertinent cells, then opens lotus and formats a new message with a subject line stating the correct shift number and date and pastes the shift report data into the body of the e-mail.

Since there is a different button to press on 3 worksheets, and I can't count on supervisors to enter numbers in any specific order, I need to be able to tell if Lotus has already opened and created an e-mail with that specific subject line to see if it needs to be created or if it exists with some information already in the body. Does anyone know if this is possible?

```
 Dim NSession As Object
 Dim NDatabase As Object
 Dim NUIWorkSpace As Object
 Dim NDoc As Object
 Dim NUIdoc As Object
 Dim WordApp As Object
 Dim WordDoc As Object

 Dim msg As String
  msg = "Leads Report " & Now() & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     "Finishing:" & vbNewLine & _
     "**PASTE Leadsheet CELLS HERE**" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

 Sheets("Leadsheet").Select
 Set newRange = Range("e4")
 mystring = RangeToString(newRange)

 Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
 Set NUIWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
 Set NDatabase = NSession.GetDatabase("", "")

 If Not NDatabase.IsOpen Then
    NDatabase.OPENMAIL

 End If

 'Create a new document
 '******************************(if statement to see 
 'if a document with specific subject line has already been 
 'created....'subject = doc.GetItemValue("subject")(0)???????
 '****************************************

 Set NDoc = NDatabase.createdocument             
      With NDoc
             .SendTo = "email@email.com" 'CHANGE THIS
             .CopyTo = ""
             .Subject = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & " Lead Report Shift " & mystring

             'Email body text, including marker text which will be replaced by the Excel cells

             .Body = msg

             .Save True, False

         End With


 'Edit the just-created document to copy and paste the Excel cells into it
 Set NUIdoc = NUIWorkSpace.editdocument(True, NDoc)


     'Find the marker text in the Body item
     'Replace it with the Excel cell
  With NUIdoc
           'leadsheet

     Workbooks("Master Shift Report Sheet.xlsm").Activate
     Sheets("LeadSheet").Select
     Range("B2:o62").Select
     ActiveWindow.zoom = 86
     Selection.copy
     Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
     Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
     With WordApp.Selection
        .PasteSpecial DataType:=4 & vbNewLine
        .wholestory
        .copy
     End With

     .gotofield ("Body")
     .findstring "**PASTE Leadsheet CELLS HERE**"
     .Paste
     'Application.CutCopyMode = False
     '.Send
     '.Close
 End With

 Set NSession = Nothing
```

anything else looks wonky don't hesitate to point it out! I'm learning.

Comment: why do the three numbers have to be in a particular order? what is that order?

Comment: are you talking about three workstations?

Comment: i keep re-reading your question and i do not see a problem that you are having. can you rephrase your question? that first long paragraph is not really necessary, it does not describe you problem at all (content and nature of data in an email is irrelevant)  .... you left out an important detail .... why does user #1 need to check that an email has been sent by user #2,  when it gets sent automatically by a button press

Comment: @jsotola I don't see anything in the question that indicates the email gets sent automatically and the send line of code is commented out.  Sounds like the supervisors are using the same workstation so it's not a user question either.  I think your over complicating it... but perhaps not...

Comment: @TUR4003 Do you really want to find saved 'drafts' or rather 'sent' messages with that subject line?  If it's just a draft (unsent) that you want to find then maybe just keep track inside of excel with another sheet as a record keeper of all e-mails created.  You can even hide this sheet if you don't want others to see it or complicate things.

Comment: @PortlandRunner, you are right. .... the long paragraph mentions the creation of an email on Lotus, it does not mention the actual sending of the email.

Comment: Once the button is pressed the email should be sent, or a message come up saying that it can't be sent. There should never be any draft half ready. Therefore there should be no need to look whether such a draft exists. If the supervisors can't enter their numbers straight your macro should reject numbers which can't be processed and tell the supervisor on the spot. If the numbers are correct, a log can be kept and code be written to prevent repeats. So, basically, I don't see how you can have the problem for which you wish to find a solution.

Comment: three different worksheets have separate macros activated by separate buttons that are pasting information about three separate workstations into the same e-mail.

Comment: They do this by finding the bookmarker in the created e-mail body and then pasting worksheet specific tables in the specified place. I need to find a way to figure out if an e-mail with a specific subject line has been created so all the information gets put into one e-mail rather than spamming everyones inboxes with a bunch of emails.

Comment: The goal is one e-mail with all the info for the entire shift. Nothing is being sent, I want to simply create the e-mail not send it. Once created with all the info in one place, supervisors would then have the opportunity to add pertinent notes such as absences, machine maintenance, downtime comments, etc. before they send. Sorry to confuse anyone with the extra paragraph. Is there a way to find out if a current draft with s specific subject line has already been created in lotus?

Comment: SIMPLY put. I want to paste info from three different places into one e-mail. This will be done using three separate macros that are user activate in no particular order. Therefore I need to find out if an e-mail draft with the specified subject line has already been created or if it needs to be created so that upon activation the macros are pasting into the same e-mail. what you see in the code is only from 1 macro, there are 2 other macros that will be using similar code.